# Data loss with roaming profiles on login on two different computers

Tags: windows-server-2003, active-directory, roaming-profile

We have a Windows server 2003 system with Active Directory and all of our users have roaming profiles. One of the users let someone login with his username and password on a different computer (2) while he was working on his own computer (1). Now when this user logs in on his own computer (1), the profile that is loaded is one that dates back many months (i think from the last time he logged on to computer 2).

My suspicion is that the profile that was cached on computer 2 from many months back when this user last logged on on this computer, on logoff, synced over the newer profile on the server. so that now when he logs in, he gets this old profile.

Now my questions:

Is it possible to retrieve te newer profile?

Is it possible to keep this from happening in the future?

Edit:
One thing that maybe is interesting to know:
computer 1 is Win 8
computer 2 is Win 7

Comment: Windows Server 2013? No wonder you're having problems.  Server 2013 doesn't exist!

Comment: My bad, i was meaning to type 2003 ;) I will correct it!

Comment: For a moment, I was hoping you meant 2012.  :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to retrieve the newer profile?

From backup?  Absolutely.  Have the user logoff, restore their profile from backup, have them log back on.

> Is it possible to keep this from happening in the future?

Absolutely.  Tell the user not to give out their credentials or logon to two computers at the same time.

Comment: That are kind of straightforward answers. Though they are both awnsers to my questions, i was hoping not to have to load my backups and just find the files in an folder somewhere. But i guess your first awnser is the only right one. As for the second awnser, i rely on Murphy's law for my users. Sooner or later someone will do this, even if i told them not to. So i would like to force this behavoir of not allowing more than one login at the time.